# Is it possible to plug hypercomplex numbers into the Riemann Zeta function?

Tags: complex-numbers, riemann-zeta, quaternions, octonions, hypercomplex-numbers

I'm aware of the more detailed question:

> [How to raise a number to a quaternion power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703593/how-to-raise-a-number-to-a-quaternion-power)

However, from a more high-level perspective (read: probably less mathematical, [hence my choice for raising this here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2142/why-is-what-is-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange-not).) I'm trying to understand this in terms of the `Riemann Zeta function` and `[multivalued functions][2]`.

From what I understand of the answer given in [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703593/how-to-raise-a-number-to-a-quaternion-power) mentioned above *it does not make sense to raise a real number to a hypercomplex (quaternion or octonion) power because it produces **multiple values***.

Doesn't this also apply to `complex number` exponents?

Isn't there a way to *plug* `hypercomplex numbers` into the Riemann Zeta function?

Comment: If $A$ is a normed $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and $s \in A$ then $n^{-s} = e^{-s \ln n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-s \ln n)^k}{k!} $ always converges and $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converges for $\|e^{-s}\| < e^{-1}$. When $s$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ then $\zeta(s)$ is given by the $\zeta(\lambda_j)$

Comment: Do you think the Euler product and other formulas stay true ?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1374462/276986) (Jordan normal form) is what we need to obtain $\|e^{-s \log n}\| \le C \|e^{-s}\|^{\log n}$

Comment: Are you interested only in quaternions and other things of Cayley-Dickson construction or you are asking a general question that includes tessarines, bicomplex numbers and split numbers (and maybe also, dual constructions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a normed finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, so $A$ is isomorphic to a sub-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$.

$\exp(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}$ converges for every $s \in A$.

Fix some $s \in A$. From the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) we obtain $s = p (\Lambda+b) p^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is a complex diagonal matrix, $b^m = 0$ and $\Lambda,b$ commute. Thus
 $$n^{-s} = \exp(-s \log n) =\exp(-p(\Lambda+b)p^{-1} \log n)=p\exp(-(\Lambda+b) \log n)p^{-1}\\=p\exp(- \Lambda\log n)\exp(-b \log n)p^{-1} = p n^{-\Lambda} \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(- \log n)^k}{k!}b^k p^{-1}$$
where $n^{-\Lambda}$ is the complex diagonal  matrix with entries $n^{-\Lambda}_{jj}=n^{-\Lambda_{jj}}$. Therefore
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} =p \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{b^k}{k!}  \zeta^{(k)}(\Lambda)  p^{-1}$$
where $\zeta^{(k)}(\Lambda)$ is the complex diagonal matrix with entries $\zeta^{(k)}(\Lambda)_{jj}=\zeta^{(k)}(\Lambda_{jj})$.

For  $A$ a general normed $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, something similar holds at least when $s$ is compact.

Therefore all the formulas about $\zeta$ stay true in this setting and up to some trivial terms, it reduces to the usual function $\zeta(z),z \in \mathbb{C}$ and its $k$-th derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

In tessarines the full answer is

$$\zeta ((a+b i)+j (c+d i))=\frac{1}{2} (\zeta (a+c+b i+d i)+\zeta (a-c-d i+b i))+\frac{1}{2} j (\zeta (a+c+b i+d i)-\zeta (a-c-d i+b i))$$

The bicomplex numbers are isomorphic to tessarins, so tessarine $j$ is equal to $-k$ in bicomplex numbers. This is a general formula that can be used for any function defined on complex numbers.